# "Desort" a matrix. Undo a sorting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

This question is basically an extension of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407030/desort-a-vector-undo-a-sorting).

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab and want to sort that matrix along one dimension:

`A = rand(3,3,5);
[B idx] = sort(A,3);`

Now `idx` is a matrix containing the "sorted" indices. How can i get back the matrix `A` using only `B` and `idx`?

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407030/desort-a-vector-undo-a-sorting) of the original question doesn't work for matrices, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried `w(ix,:)=v`, where `:` represents "ignored" dimensions?

Comment: Do you mean in my case something like: w(:,:,idx) = B? That doesn't work due to "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch."

Comment: `w(idx)=B` works but it is incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sort the indices `idx`to get back the original indices. Rest of the work would involve getting the formatted row and column indices corresponding to all those dim-3 indices. The implementation would look something like this -

```
[~,dim3idx] = sort(idx,3);

[m,n,r] = size(B);
[rowidx,colidx,~] = ndgrid(1:m,1:n,1:r);

Aout = B(sub2ind(size(B),rowidx,colidx,dim3idx))
```

Please note that for performance, one can get the linear indices generated by `sub2ind` alternatively with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) directly from the size parameters and thus also avoid `ndgrid`, like so -

```
Aout = B(bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@plus,(1:m)',m*(0:n-1)),m*n*(dim3idx-1)))
```